# To perform getTransactionReceipt on old blocks do I need full or fast node?

Tags: go-ethereum, receipts

If I need to run eth_getTransactionReceipt(txhash) on old transactions, will a fast node suffice or do I need to run a full node? I have heard conflicting answers and would prefer not to download a full sync if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast synced node will work. Transaction receipts are part of blocks so as long as a block is downloaded you can get all receipts from it.